# bitcoin-qt and ubuntu 18.10

Tags: bitcoin-core, ubuntu

bitcoin-qt worked well on Ubuntu 18.04, after the upgrade to 18.10 it won't start anymore. Can't find any hints in log-files.
Help appreciated!
kr Heinz

Comment: I have the same problem, what happens when you run `bitcoin-qt` from the terminal?

Comment: Nothing happens, no error or any other message turns up.

Answer (score 1):

This may be connected to the fact that Berkeley DB can't be built on Ubuntu 18.10:

```
Can’t build Berkley database on ubuntu 18.10. During call to make install getting error: definition of ‘int __atomic_compare_exchange(db_atomic_t*, atomic_value_t, atomic_value_t)’ ambiguates built-in declaration ‘bool __atomic_compare_exchange(long unsigned int, volatile void*, void*, void*, int, int)’
```

Comment: Some patches
1. http://lists.busybox.net/pipermail/buildroot/2018-May/220910.html
2. https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/libdb-4.8/
3. https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/db4.8/